# How to terminate a shell process in Gradle build after ctrl+c

Tags: shell, gradle, groovy

How can a process created in cmd.execute()-call be terminated when the Gradle build is terminated with ctrl-c.

In this example the calcTask-task starts the shell process 'longRunningProcess.bat', which is a 'sleep 300'. When the Gradle build is aborted with ctrl+c the 'sleep' process is still active. The exception does handle errors in the shell but not ctrl+c.

```
apply plugin: "groovy"

dependencies {
  compile gradleApi()
}

task CreateLongRunningProcess(type: DefaultTask) {
    def file = new File('longRunningProcess.bat')
    file.write '@ECHO Start calculating - please wait 5 minutes.\n'
    file << '@sleep 300\n'
    file << '@ECHO Finished calculating.\n'
}

class CalcTask extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def calculate() {
        String cmd = './longRunningProcess.bat'
        try {
            def proc = cmd.execute()
            proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            println 'Exception occured'
        }
    }
}

task calcTask(type: CalcTask) {
    dependsOn(CreateLongRunningProcess)
}
```

---

```
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
$ ./gradlew -q calcTask
Start calculating - please wait 5 minutes.

<Aborted with ctrl+c>
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
 t035678    1900       1 ?        16:55:58 /usr/bin/sleep
$ kill 1900
$ ./longRunningProcess.bat
Start calculating - please wait 5 minutes.
<Aborted with ctrl+c>
Finished calculating.
$ ps -ef | grep sleep
$ ./gradlew --version
<snip>

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-12-06 09:05:06 UTC
Revision:     cf7821a6f79f8e2a598df21780e3ff7ce8db2b82

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          9.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 9.0.1+11)
OS:           Windows 7 6.1 amd64
```

Comment: According to https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1128 it takes 10 seconds for an interrupt before a daemon will kill a JavaTask. I think you might be running into the same kind of thing here. Could you check to see if the sleep is stopped automatically after 10+ seconds?